# ActivityNotFoundException handling

Tags: android, android-intent, exception

I haven't done exception handling in a few years and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have an app that opens another one of my apps and if the user doesn't already have the other app I want the current one to redirect to the Play Store. Right now if the app isn't installed the program is force closing. My current code is:

```
try{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.app.package");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(intent);
   }
catch(ActivityNotFoundException activityNotFound){
    Intent playStoreIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("market://details?id=my.app.package"));
    startActivity(playStoreIntent);
   }
```

I have a feeling I'm doing something really stupid and misuing the `catch` function. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can u post ur logcat exception?

Comment: try after remove `intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);`

Comment: getLaunchIntentForPackage() returns null if "my.app.package" doesn't exists and so you're getting a NullPointerException for calling addCategory(...) on a intent that is null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this code. Explanations given in comment

```
String packageName = "my.app.package";
try{
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        //if application not installed, intent to get launcher will be null
        if(intent != null) {
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
                   //launch play store with package name
            Intent playStoreIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse("market://details?id=my.app.package"));
                    startActivity(playStoreIntent); 
        }
       }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException activityNotFound){
        // to handle play store not installed scenario
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                .parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName));
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I noticed that some people don't have the Play Store installed, causing the ActivityNotFoundException. Who doesn't have the Play Store installed? weird! Thanks for the code to open it in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: try catch is not required.

```
 Intent LaunchIntent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packagename);

 if(null!=LaunchIntent)
    {
       startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    }
else
    {
      //intent to open the market.
    }
```